# Question regarding a specific "difference" between Service and IntentService

Tags: android, service, queue

We have been testing a little bit with Service and IntentServices in Android. As far as we understood one of the benefits of the IntentService is it's own thread and worker queue...
After testing we noticed that if you send a 100 intents to both services they will both  start executing sequentially...

Thats somewhat expected form the IntentService because of it's worker queue, but how does Android behave regarding to several request to a non-multithreaded Service ? Cause it seems like it has some kind of underlying worker queue as well ? Or maybe some kind of Intents-queue which is kept by the Android system itself ?
And if so, is there any way to attach to it, for example to see it's length/size ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but how does Android behave regarding to several request to a non-multithreaded Service ?

Calls to `startService()` are queued in the message queue for the main application thread of the sender, just like calls to any GUI operation (e.g., `setText()`), calls to `startActivity()`, and so on.

`IntentService` has a second queue, inside the service itself, for received `Intents` to be processed by the background thread.

Comment: ok that explains it somewhat, but just for fun (if it can be called that), let's say you have two applications running that both send several startService() requests to the same Service... What will the order be ? Cause according to your explanation there would be two message queues involved, so is there some kind of "reglatory organ" at the end of those that sends the next Intent to the Service itself ? Btw thanks for your help Mark, once again...

Comment: @TiGer: " let's say you have two applications running that both send several startService() requests to the same Service... What will the order be ?" -- the order will be indeterminate. The best we can say is that each client's requests will be executed in the order they send them, but the requests may be interleaved based on when those requests were actually processed by each client's main application thread.